# Linking Problems with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, libraries

I have a problem concidered with linking to my own static library:

Simply adding the path of the *.h and *.lib file is not enough.

The include of my *.h works fine and I can use classes from it.
So there are no syntax errors.

But when I try to build it I get "error LNK2001".

I can solve this problem by adding "#pragma comment(lib,"MyLibrary.lib")" and it works perfectly fine. But as far as i know it should work without that.

The boost-libraries work perfectly fine without the pragma comment and they are included the same way as my own library is :/

Anyone knows how to fix this or why it doesn't work without the pragma comment?

***EDIT:***

I added the Path to my *.h file to "Properties->VC++-Directories->Include-Directories"
and the Path to my *.lib file to "Properties->VC++-Directories->Library-Directories"
(I am not sure about the english names because I'm not using the english version but I guess you know what i mean =) )

Did the same with the boost libraries
(And according to what I've found on the internet this should have been enough :/ )

Comment: Where/how did you add the lib file? Also, you may want to check whether [`boost/config/auto_link.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/config/auto_link.hpp) is included through some other file, it contains `#pragma comment` for at least a number of boost libraries.

Comment: Did you add the actual lib file to `Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies`? If not, you'll need your `#pragma comment` as an alternative way of adding it to the linking stage.

Comment: Just found this out a second ago and wanted to post that i solved it by my own :D Works fine =) Thank you =)

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer so that other people can benefit from it

Comment: I wanted to do that but I can't because I dont have enough reputation :/  I can do it tomorrow after the 8h waiting time for that